# Hide pdf object's sidebar in Chrome (but keep the toolbar)

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, embed

I'm rendering a PDF with an object tag like this:

```
              <object
                class="document-preview"
                data="/path/to/the_file.pdf"
                style="border: none;"
                width="100%"
                height="650"
                type="application/pdf"
              ><p>Sorry, this document could not be displayed.</object>
```

I know that I can hide the toolbar AND sidebar by adding `#toolbar=0` to the data attribute like so:

```
data="/path/to/the_file.pdf#toolbar=0"
```

However, I just want to hide the sidebar (which shows a thumbnail for each page), and show the top bar with download, print etc options.

Is there a similar hash-param I can use, like "#sidebar=0"?  (that doesn't work, i tried it already)

Answer (score 0):

Found it!  The sidebar can be hidden with

```
#navpanes=0
```